# How to import data from a file into Redis database?

Tags: laravel, database, redis

I am a very NOOB in Redis and this is the first time that I am using this application.I hope you can help me.
I am trying to create a list of words from a dictionary and put in into Redis database. I have a text file containing 200,000 words. How can I put it in my database?

I am using Laravel and My Redis configuration is working fine, because I am able to execute this command.

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
Redis::set('name', 'MYname');
$name = Redis::get('name');
echo $name;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the dictionary used for?
If it is just 200,000 words, you can simply put all of them into a set.

```
for word in text_file:
    Redis::sadd('dictionary_name', word)
```

and use

```
Redis::sismember('dictionary_name', word)
```

to check whethor or not the word is in the dictionary.

Here's documentation about [redis set](http://redis.io/commands#set)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry but I am very new to Redis. Is Redis::sadd('dictionary_name', word) will be executed once or do I need to execute it for every word?

Comment: [sadd](http://redis.io/commands/sadd) can take a bunch of members ( but frankly i don't know if it can take an array that contains 200,000 members). And the time complexity of sadd is: O(N) where N is the number of members to be added. So using a single sadd with 200,000 arguments and using a for loop with 1 argument each both take O(N) time. I think a for loop is fine in this case. If the number is much more than 200,000, perhaps split them into batches is a better solution.

Comment: There's no problem loading 200K words in one go - that's about 3MB (e.g. SOWPODS), but another consideration is whether your application is using a remote Redis server. If you need to go over the network, you'd want to "batch" your operations to minimize latency so 1) I'd avoid doing SADD for each word and 2) use Redis' pipelining.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I forgot to mention pipelining. Thanks for adding that. And your information is super informative and inspiring, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to upload my data through this command.

```
$filename = 'file.txt';

$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

if ($fp) {
    $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}

$redis = Redis::connection();
Redis::sadd('dictionary', $array);
```

Comment: The line reads $redis = Redis::connection();  does not seem to do anything, does it? $redis is not being referenced.

Comment: I believe OP is using Laravel Facades, which is why it's not being referenced anywhere.